# Selenium Appium Java Android Chrome Browser

Tags: java, android, selenium, google-chrome, appium

I am doing automation to test Video on Android Chrome browser using Selenium Appium Web Driver. I have to read text from a field. The text exists on page for 5 seconds. Appium takes approx 10 sec to process the request. I am not able to read the object because of long processing time of Appium. I tried all possible options. Can you please help me to fix the issue

Comment: This is an interesting common problem. Can you please clarify on the following:

1. How are you setting up Appium in the project? Are the Appium capabilities handled in the same class as the automation code or pre-initialised? It is very important to know this information.

2. What approach are you using for the automation? If the automation involves reading/writing dynamic content from a page, the Page Object Model approach is very well suited, are you doing something similar?

Share code/snippet if necessary.

Comment: Also I think it is very important to organise your automation code such that in a chronological order(if it needs be) you prioritise on the target element content, in such a scenario you described. Feel free to describe/mention the other requests you mentioned that Appium is processing.

Comment: My script is running on Android Device -> Chrome browser. Workflow is: Open url HTML 5 video player starts playing the video At the start of video I get Video Ad Duration of Ad is 6 seconds and appears in a text field I have to read the text value.

Comment: Can you refactor your code a bit and try the same with the following:

1. AppiumDriver and MobileElement(if working on a cross-platform mobile automation).

2. AndroidDriver and AndroidElement if working specifically on Android platform.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **expilicitWait**

```
public static void ExplicitWait(WebElement element) {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOf(element));
    }
```

It will wait 30 seconds until the element is visible. if the element is not visible within 30 seconds then exception is thrown.

Comment: I think this is not the problem being addressed. The problem is that the target content of the target element gets unavailable by the time Appium is processing the requests.

Comment: My script is running on Android Device -> Chrome browser.
Workflow is:
Open url
HTML 5 video player starts playing the video
At the start of video I get Video Ad
Duration of Ad is 6 seconds and appears in a text field
I have to read the text value.

Comment: xpath /hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View[4]/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[5]/android.view.View

Can you please guide me to fix the issue?